# unable to download antlr when building project

Tags: android, dart, antlr, flutter

I'm trying to start working with flutter. But I get this error when executing the `flutter run` on the app.

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
Could not download antlr.jar (org.antlr:antlr:3.5.2)
Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/antlr/antlr/3.5.2/antlr-3.5.2.jar'.
Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/antlr/antlr/3.5.2/antlr-3.5.2.jar'.
Connect to jcenter.bintray.com:443 [jcenter.bintray.com/108.168.243.150] failed: Connection timed out"
```

I downloaded antlr-3.5.2.jar, but I don't know what to do with it to solve the problem.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: That doesn't sound like a file that is needed to build our standard app template. Can you say a little about what additional dependencies you have added to your `pubspec.yaml` file?

Comment: Its weird, I can't reproduce it any more. It got fixed by itself! Anyway, it was the same basic app that is created when you run flutter create <name>, I changed nothing!